# Jersey Resource .class loading

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, websphere, jersey

I have the Jersey resource classes bundled within a larger WAR as JAR file which is now residing underneath WEB-INF/lib folder on Websphere Application Server. I have the correct web.xml entry(WEB-INF/web.xml) but still on the server, the scan appears to be not able to lookup the Resource classes which are bundled as a JAR. I was looking at a few threads, and the suggestion was to not bundle Resources as a JAR but instead load the classes seperately underneath /WEB-INF/classes.

```
<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
 <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>blah.blah.blah</param-value>
 </init-param>
 </servlet>
```

> com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes..at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.processRootResources(WebApplicationImpl.java:1064)

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are issues outlined in the blog post from Rohit here on various jersey issues with specific versions of WebSphere, can you please see if anything there helps you?

http://wasdynacache.blogspot.com/2011/08/jax-rs-implementations-in-websphere.html

Comment: This issue is specific to WAS 6.1 and the Jersey JARs we are using. We had to write our own scanners to lookup WEB-INF/lib

Answer (score 0):

Having the classes in a JAR vs in WEB-INF/classes makes no difference. Either your package name(s) are wrong in the web.xml, something else in your web.xml is configured incorrectly, or your resource classes aren't annotated properly (or, possibly, some WebSphere devilry is at work--I've never used it myself, but I've heard of really strange class path problems with it). If you show a resource class, a full web.xml, and more of the logs around the error, someone might be able to point out what's going wrong.

Comment: how about having a JAR with Resource classes underneath WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: That's what I meant when I said it makes no difference. Classes inside JARs in WEB-INF/lib are on the classpath just the same as classes that are in WEB-INF/classes. Anything that loads classes from one place will load classes from the other as well.

Comment: The problem is, if I drop the Resource .class files underneath WEB-INF/classes, it works fine. But unfortunately the same .class within JAR bundle underneath WEB-INF/lib is failing. As in, the scan is not able to lookup the Resource classes within JAR. I have a @Path annotation for the root of class. Is there any other annotation or config I'll have to specify to make it aware of being in JAR. I am sorry, this is making me go round in circles

Comment: As I think about it, it might cause problems if you have the same root package in WEB-INF/classes and in a jar in WEB-INF/lib, depending on how Jersey does package scanning. I.e. does your package `blah.blah.blah` exist in both WEB-INF/classes and in the jar where your resource class is? It might also be a problem with your jar. If you include the output of `jar tf <your jar file>` in your question, we can see if it looks right.

Comment: It could be the project structure, the complete package is within /WAR/WEB-INF/lib/(x.y.z.a.b within JAR) but a partial package exists within /WAR/x/y/z. Maybe it errors because it cannot complete the package resolve in (/WAR/x/y/z). I have the complete package name in init param. It must be not all going into the JAR for scan?

Comment: If by "complete package name in init param" you mean the "x.y.z.a.b" package, then no, it'll work fine like that. Your problem is elsewhere, and if you're not going to show any more code than you've shown, then nobody is likely to be able to help you any further.

Comment: JAR vs WEB-INF/classes makes a big difference due to the bugs mentioned in the accepted answer. Your answer is highly misleading.