# Jersey URISchemeScanner 

Tags: java, web-services, rest, websphere, jersey

A few days back, I ran into Jersey deployment issues which I posted here

[Jersey Resource .class loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606919/jersey-resource-class-loading)

We were able to use an alternative deployment mechanism by extending javax.ws.rs.core.Application and put in a temporary fix. But on researching more, I came across Jersey Scanners which can be implemented within our code. This can be made to lookup specific JARs within our project deploy structure. I was looking up the web, but could not find any specific examples of how the URISchemeScanner needs to be integrated within our code. (web.xml configuration, etc ...) Appreciate if I could be pointed in the right direction

Comment: What version of websphere are you running?

Answer (score 1):

from PackagesNamesScanner javadoc:

"Further schemes may be registered by registering an implementation of UriSchemeScanner in the META-INF/services file whose name is the the fully qualified class name of UriSchemeScanner."

See: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.12/jersey/com/sun/jersey/core/spi/scanning/PackageNamesScanner.html

Comment: Thx for your reply. I created a  META-INF/services/com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.UriSchemeScanner and within the file have my implementation class's  (blah.blah.OurScanner) fully qualified name. Also the implementation code's getScheme() has a wsjar registration now, which is specific to WAS 6.1. Still the scanning is not working. Anything I am missing?

Comment: I added the META-INF/services entry within my JAR which has the resources in it , and the jersey-core.jar. But still no luck. Running into "The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes."

Comment: not sure. You are using PackagesResourceConfig (http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.12/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/PackagesResourceConfig.html), right? There might be problem with even discovering that META-INF/services file due to some classloader restrictions, but I won't be able to help with those..

Comment: and can you confirm that your scanner implementation is (or is not) called?

Comment: I don't think it is being called, I setup breakpoints within my scanner source and the server startup logs don't have any entry of OurScanner. We are using 1.1.5.1 JARS with WAS 6.1, are you aware of any specific JAR version, where this problem of looking up WEB-INF/lib/JAR could have been solved

Comment: ah, thats pretty old.. can you upgrade to 1.12?

Comment: that was my first though, would love to update, but that will be an architecture decision. will get back to you after my tests. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: We tried integrating 1.12 with WAS 6.1 but we are now running into version incompatibility issues. WAS 6.1 is running on top of  Java 5 but Jersey 1.12 appears to be compiled with Java 1.6. During compile and run time, we are running into UnspportedClassVersionErrors. We cannot update our JVM or WAS to Java 1.6 at this time. Is there any version you are aware of, which has fixed the scanning issue of looking up WEB-INF/lib, but compiles with Java 1.5? We are having a hard time figuring out a scanning fix to our problem. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the problem with WAS 7. What we have done is remove the scanning Init Param itself from the web.xml and copy the Jar which contains resources in the Web-Inf Lib folder of the Web project. Then it will work. Adding J2EE dependency in the ear alone wont work.

I am using jersey 1.12 but the default scanner still have issue

Can you share the custom scanner modification you have done so that I can also try with that?

Comment: We registered wsjar scheme to the Custom Scanner code, and tried integrating. But still the auto scanning failed to lookup Jersey Resources. Currently we are  extending javax.ws.rs.core.Application by creating a manual deployment registry.